# When does $\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}} \frac{1}{|p|^2}$ diverges?

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

We know $\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}} \frac{1}{|p|^2}$ diverges where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes set of all primes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (because that sum is greater that $\sum_{p \equiv 3 \mod 4} \frac{1}{p}$, which diverges). Now my question is can we classify set of all algebraic integers $\mathbb{\alpha} \in \mathbb{C}$ for which the sum $\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}} \frac{1}{|p|^2}$ diverges where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes set of all primes in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ ?

Comment: what is $|p|^2$ with $p \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ ? you know that  the [Dedekind zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_zeta_function) $\zeta_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)}(s)$ always diverges at $s=1$

Comment: Here I want $|p|$ to be usual norm on $\mathbb{C}$ (not product of conjugates of $\alpha$)

Comment: $N_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}}(p) = \prod_{\sigma \in Aut(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}) } \sigma(p)$ and if $n = [ \mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}] > 2$ then $|p|^{2} \ll N_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}}(p)$ so that it diverges ??

Comment: Another problem is the infinite unit group for fields that are not imaginary quadratic.